# Magento 2 : add extra validation rules for an existing shipping carrier

Tags: magento2.3, shipping-methods, validation

This question is about javascript carrier validation in the checkout page. Depending on the validation result, some carriers may disappear from the displayed list if validation failed for them.

I found documentation about how to [Add custom shipping carrier validations](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_carrier.html). This doc explains how to create from scratch a brand new validator and its own validation rules and how to register them and how to add them in the checkout layout etc. etc...
The point is : I don't need to create a new validator from scratch. The carrier already exists, its validator too. I just want to add an extra validation rule to the existing ones (and fyi, I want this carrier validation to fail if shipping address telephone is not a mobile phone).

Is there a way to inject my own rule in the existing ones (with a mixin maybe ?) or do I have to go through the full creation as described in the official doc, to end up pushing an additional validator for this carrier ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to myself : NO. It appears there are no shortcuts to this method.

Answer (score 0):

In Your Shipping Model File(eg. Career.php) add below like condition

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
        /**
         * here add custom condition and return false if not matching in your condition
         */
        if ($telephone = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone()) {
            if($telephone != 'your_variable'){
                return false;   // it will not execute furthure code
            }           
        }

        // here your shipping main code
}
```

Comment: Is collectRates() called somehow by javascript code in the checkout page ? Because I'm asking about JS validation, with dynamic refresh of carriers list in this checkout.
Also, I don't own this carrier, so I guess I would have to make a plugin instead.

Comment: better way is I suggested already..for js look below link. you must have to go through it there are no any shortcut. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_carrier.html

Comment: This is for JS validation.
I finally followed this doc, without shortcut. Thank you.

Comment: great !!....adding answer for helping someone

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow Below Document for JS Validation.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_carrier.html